# What is the proper way to do a search filtering on a list php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My objective is apply a search filter on a post lists

My 4 fields of filtering are **"owner first name"** **"owner last name"** **"post type"** and **"date of creation"**

I have created a function called searchPosts where I prepare an SQL request according to the fields that are set are not empty.

```
   public function searchPosts($ownerFirstname, $ownerLastname, $carteId, $date, $postType){
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    // Connect to the database
    // Prepare the query for only the fields that are set and are not empty
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM annonce, user, annonce_type ";
    var_dump($date);

    $date = (int) $date;
    $postType = (int) $postType;
    if(!empty($ownerFirstname) || !empty($ownerLastname) || !empty($carteId) || (!empty($date) && $date != 0)  || (!empty($postType) && $postType != 0)){

        $sql .= "WHERE ";

    }

    if(!empty($ownerFirstname)){
        $sql .= "annonce.annonce_owner_id = user.user_id AND user.user_firstname LIKE '%" . $ownerFirstname . "%' ";
        if(!empty($ownerLastname)){
            $sql .= "AND user.user_lastname LIKE '%" . $ownerLastname . "%' ";
            $isSetFirstAndLastName = true;
        }
        $isSetFirstName = true;
    }'

    if(!empty($ownerLastname) && !isset($isSetFirstAndLastName)){

        $sql .= "annonce.annonce_owner_id = user.user_id AND user.user_lastname LIKE '%" . $ownerLastname . "%' ";
    }

   // executing the sql request...
    var_dump($sql);
}
```

Is there a way to query a php object that has been retrieved from the database ? Am I doing it the right way ? And how to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the proper way to do it !

```
  public function searchPosts($ownerFirstname, $ownerLastname, $carteId, $date, $postType, $pageNumber, $numberOfItems){
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    // Connect to the database
    // Prepare the query for only the fields that are set and are not empty
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM annonce, user, annonce_type WHERE annonce.annonce_owner_id = user.user_id AND annonce_type.annonce_type_id = annonce.annonce_type_id ";

    $date = (int) $date;
    $postType = (int) $postType;
    $pageNumber = (int) $pageNumber;
    $numberOfItems = (int) $numberOfItems;

    if(!empty($ownerLastname)){
        $sql .= "AND user.user_lastname LIKE '%" . $ownerLastname . "%' ";
        $isSetFirstAndLastName = true;
    }
    if(!empty($ownerFirstname)){
        $sql .= "AND user.user_firstname LIKE '%" . $ownerFirstname . "%' ";
        $isSetFirstName = true;    
    }

    if(!empty($date) && ($date == 1 || $date == 2 || $date == 3 || $date == 4)){

        if($date == 1){
            $sql .= "AND annonce.annonce_datecreation > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
        }
        if($date == 2){
            $sql .= "AND annonce.annonce_datecreation > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)";
        }
        if($date == 3){
            $sql .= "AND annonce.annonce_datecreation > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)";
        }
        if($date == 4){
            $sql .= "AND annonce.annonce_datecreation < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)";
        }
        $isSetDate = true;

    }

    if(!empty($carteId)){
        $sql .= "AND annonce.annonce_carte_id LIKE '%" . $carteId . "%' ";
        $isSetCarteId = true;

    }

    if(!empty($postType) && ($postType == 0 || $postType == 1 || $postType == 2)){
        $sql .= "AND annonce.annonce_type_id = annonce_type.annonce_type_id AND annonce_type.annonce_type_id = " . $postType . " ";
    }
    // TODO : add order by date creation
    $firstItem = ($pageNumber - 1) * 10;

    $sql .= "LIMIT " . $firstItem .  "," . $numberOfItems . " ";

    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $data = $result->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}
```